# How can I use nested TouchableOpacity?

Tags: react-native

I have the following component

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { console.log("Hello World }}>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I want to then wrap this component inside of a HoC, which wraps the WrappedComponent in a `TouchableOpacity`.

```
const withFoo = WrappedComponent => class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { console.log("Hello HoC") }}>
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

However, when I click on the component, I only see "Hello World". I do not see any output from the HoC.

Answer (score 2):

We can use TouchableOpacity in our code. But if size of subcomponent is same as main component then you won't get any result for main component.

```
<TouchableOpacity 
style={{width:50, height:50, backgroundColor:'red}} 
onPress={() => { console.log("Hello World }}>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Try to update style for subcomponent and check click method for both one.